# Why doesn`t Android allow you to have capital letters in resource names?

Tags: android, initialization, constraints

Its whats the title says:

Why doesn`t Android allow you to have capital letters in resources names such as drawables and xmls etc?  Also it wont allow resources names to start with a number. Why is that so?

Comment: When you say "asset names", do you mean "resource names"? There are no particular rules for files in `assets/` AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, exactly. I've edited myy question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource names cannot start with a number, because resource names are turned into Java fields in the `R` class, and Java identifiers cannot start with a number.

Resource files are limited to a-z, 0-9, and underscore characters. Partly, that is due to the Java identifier rules, as Java identifiers cannot have arbitrary characters. In terms of the case, my assumption is that they wanted to avoid problems on Windows, particularly in the early days of Android development, as Windows historically ignored case with filenames.

Comment: this about answers my question. Looking out for other answers too. I was just wondering because i have 80+ xml files that i need to rename to suit specs.